# WSASend: Is all I/O initiated by a given thread still canceled when that thread exits?

Tags: c++, windows, asynchronous, io

http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2008/02/major-vista-overlapped-io-change.html

The article above states:

> Vista now allows threads to issue overlapped I/O requests and exit and it 
>   will still process the requests and queue them to the completion port.

But in the online documentation Microsoft still has a warning:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742203(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Note  All I/O initiated by a given thread is canceled when that thread exits. 
>   For overlapped sockets, pending asynchronous operations can fail if the 
>   thread is closed before the operations complete.

Can any one tell me if this MSDN Note/Waring is still valid for IOCP in combination with WSASend on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: Either it's doc rot (highly possible), or still highly valid. I would suggest writing a test app and using that to verify.

Comment: Tough call, MSDN doesn't help.  What's possibly overlooked is the role of a thread-pool thread issuing the I/O request.  The normal case.  You'd of course expect such a tp-thread to quickly exit and not wait for completion.  But it doesn't quit either, it stays in the pool.